# Active Mixed Content Vulnerability - http://110005487.collect.igodigital.com/collect.js

Tags: javascript

We are using Sitecore 9.3.
We have a vulnerability reported in Qualys scan - "Active mixed content vulnerability".

**Threat**

An active mixed content vulnerability has been discovered while loading the web page. In mixed-content web applications, the web page is delivered to the browser over secure channel but additional content is delivered over non secure channel. We classify the mixed content into Active mixed content with reference to Mozilla Firefox browser behavior. Active mixed-content Vulnerability is reported if any of the following content are discovered when loading the web page to be delivered over non secure channel. script, link, iframe, XMLHttpRequest requests, object, applet

**Impact**

The non secure channels(HTTP) is not encrypted and hence vulnerable to sniffing attacks. These non secure channels can be exploited to gain access to wide set of capabilities such as forging requests, stealing cookies or DOM data leakage.

**Solution**

The solution to mixed content vulnerability is simply load sub-resources of web page over HTTPS. Apart from loading sub-resource over HTTPS, it can mitigated using following two options: 1. HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) 2. Content Security Policy (CSP)

**Finding**

The page at https://portalname/fr was loaded over HTTPS, but following requested an insecure resource-

http://110005487.collect.igodigital.com/collect.js

But I checked the application code and we are not referencing above link anywhere. Does anyone know if this is internally used by sitecore?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure this is not injected by any code you are using? eg if you are using GTM marketers often inject all kinds of these things that way. Use the developer tools in your browser to find this request and its initiator.

Comment: @Gatogordo Thank you for your comment. I really appreciate it, but this request is not showing up on the Network tab. That is why I posted this question here.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is definitely not used by Sitecore. This script is most likely inserted via Tag Manager container or referenced by another script.

Follow the steps below to find what triggers this request:

1. Open Developer Tools in your browser and navigate to the Network tab
2. Reload your web page to record all requests in the Network tab
3. Find the problematic request and select it
4. Go to the Initiator tab, it will show the request call stack or request initiator chain similar to this:

[image: Request initiator]

This can help you understand what has triggered this request and where it is coming from.

Comment: Hi @Anna thank you for taking out time to answer my question. I really appreciate it. This request is not showing in the Network tab that is why I posted the question here.

Comment: Hi @NewbieHere, it's possible that browsers block this script because it's loading via HTTP instead of HTTPS. It looks like the script `collect.igodigital.com/collect.js` is a Salesforce Marketing Cloud script https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_ctc_install_collect_code.htm&type=5, so you should reach out to your marketing team who is looking after web tracking and ask them to check how the script is configured.